# Folder's in public_html are not getting accessed

Tags: cpanel

I have a problem in accessing folders inside the public_html directory. When I create a folder inside public_html and try to access it through browser as www.website_name.com/folder_name I am not able to do so.

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: please let me know what type of detail you want

Comment: Is this your main domain? Do you have addon domains? Can you access files (instead of folders) from the public_html folder?

Comment: yes this is my main domain, i am not able to access any folder inside it just it is accessing main website

Answer (score 0):

Your website_name.com domain should be pointed to 'public_html/' (document directory) ,  Then you can access the folders like that you mentioned 'www.website_name.com/folder_name'

step 1: click on -> "addon domain"

step 2: then you can see a table like this ->

Addon Domains|***Document Root***|  Username | Redirects to|Actions

step 3: in that table you can see your website entry
change the second column "Document root" to  "public_html/" if your website files kept in the "public_html". if the domain document root is pointed to the "public_html" you can access the files like this -> "www.website_name.com/folder"

**if your website document root is pointed like "public_html/mysite/" - > then you can get the subfolders of "mysite" folder**

Comment: are you using shared hosting ?

Comment: if you are using control panel then you just go to "domains." then find out the entry (website_name.com) in the control panel . on that same row there is document root . just change it as "public_html" .

Comment: yes i am using shared hosting. Under doamins which option should i choose

Comment: click on -> "addon domain"

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Cpanel, Please Check the folder permission you added. Permission should be 0755 to be readable/accessible to the public.

My Directory Structure:

```
/public_html/sample.xyz.com/index.html
```

For my case `index.html` file permission was "0750" and it was not visible to public. Modified the folder permission to "0755" and It starts working.!!